# Spring Cloud JDBC Backend

Tags: spring, jdbc, cloud, config, backend

I'm trying configure JDBC Backend for my Spring Cloud Config Server, but I'm not able to do that and documentation provided by Spring is very weak.

I created a table named PROPERTIES in accordance with documentation in http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Edgware.SR1/multi/multi__spring_cloud_config_server.html#_jdbc_backend

I fill this table with some informations, for example:

```
APPLICATION: positions
PROFILE: dev
KEY: myop1
VALUE: myop1-value
LABEL: null
```

My bootstrap.yml have the follow lines:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: configserver
```

My application.yml have the follow lines:

```
endpoints:
  shutdown:
    enabled: true

server:
   port: ${port:8888}
spring:
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
  datasource:
    platform: oracle
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.100.117:1521:orcl
    username: my-username
    password: my-password
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
  jpa:
    database: Oracle
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
  database:
     driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
```

When I run my aplication using goal spring-boot:run everything works fine, no error message is shown, but when I try to access my browser for http://localhost:8888/positions/dev the browser show the following information:

```
{"name":"positions","profiles":["dev"],"label":null,"version":null,"state":null,"propertySources":[]}
```

Can anyone help with this situation?

Comment: Hi did you got any success ?? I am getting this issue. How to I solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The label property cannot be null. If you don't give a value to label, it's automatically looking for a "master" value. So, basically you can set "master" to your null labels.